# Youtube iFrame javascript API solution needed for Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube-api

I am trying to get into Youtube iFrame API with javascript.
There is a great example provided by Javier on:

http://poselab.com/youtube-javascript-player-api/

Even more simple demo example is provided here:

http://poselab.com/contenidos/youtube-api/youtube-api-with-iframe.html

Source code looks like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>YouTube JavaScript Player API with iframe</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>

<script>    
    //create the player object
    var player = {};

    //add functions to player on ready
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player.ytcplayer1 = new YT.Player('ytcplayer1');
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="ytcplayer1" type="text/html" width="570" height="321" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/NvQBJDeV6G4?&amp;autoplay=0&amp;theme=dark&amp;enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>

    <p class="controls">
        <a href="javascript: player.ytcplayer1.playVideo();">Play</a>
        <a href="javascript: player.ytcplayer1.pauseVideo();">Pause</a>
        <a href="javascript: player.ytcplayer1.stopVideo();">Stop</a>
    </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Example is great and very clear to understand. However it works on Chrome, but not on Mozilla Firefox. Instead of getting youtube video playing on FireFox, I get all page gone and this kind of output:

```
[object Object]
```

Could someone suggest how to rewrite javascript code so that it works on Firefox as well?

Comment: Have you used Firebug to debug this?  If you google `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` there are lots of hits for people debugging similar behavior. Have you looked at these links?

Comment: I was going through Google's reference https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference but didn't find what I need. Yes, I was searching other posts, but again not many help.

Comment: Java console gives quite a lot of errors. As I am not fluent in javascript, I couldn't find the solution. Especially having different behavior on different browsers is kind a complicated topic for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In actuality, Firefox is handling the code correctly and webkit-based browsers aren't implementing the spec properly ... when an anchor element has an href attribute that is not a URL fragment of the current page, it is supposed to resolve the URL according to the provided protocol, and either load the resulting document (when there is one) in the window or pass it off to be handled by an external program (depending on what the protocol is). So when you click on an anchor that references a URL with the javascript: protocol, in this case the resulting document is an object (because that's what these particular YouTube API calls return) and that's what Firefox shows you.

Webkit's non-standard behavior is to, when encountering an href attribute with a javascript protocol, default to not returning anything to the browser window. To implement that same behavior in Firefox, your code should be:

```
<p class="controls">
    <a href="javascript:player.ytcplayer1.playVideo(); void(0);">Play</a>
    <a href="javascript:player.ytcplayer1.pauseVideo(); void(0);">Pause</a>
    <a href="javascript:player.ytcplayer1.stopVideo(); void(0);">Stop</a>
</p>
```

One final thing to mention, though, is that in practice you should try to avoid having any javascript links altogether like this; it isn't deprecated, per se, but it's pretty frowned upon (not to mention detrimental to accessibility). Instead, you should either:

- Use the onclick attribute of the anchor element to execute the javascript, or
- Use external javascript code (so as to separate your function and content) that binds the desired actions to the text links.

Comment: Thanks! I've tested your suggestion and it really works! You saved a lot of time! Really thanks!